# RViz2 manually add displays from panel plugin

Tags: rviz, turtlebot3, rviz-plugins

I'm making a RViz plugin for the Turtlebot3 as testing ground before making it for my actual robot. What I want is to essentially launch the Turtlebot cartographer launch file that opens a map and laser scan in RViz, but do it without opening a new RViz instance since it crashes the current one that has my plugin opened.

An idea I had was to track down the callback of the 'Add' Button that allows the user to add a display to RViz, and to somehow call this function myself. Doing this would allow me to add the required displays myself, instead of having them boot up with the Turtlebot RViz config file. So far, I haven't been able to find a way to call this function.

After adding the needed displays, I could then manually run the cartographer node responsible for actually reading the laser scan.

My goal in the end is to have a button that starts the localization, boots up the cartographer and shows it in the current RViz window, a Save Map button I have already implemented which runs the nav2_map_server map_saver_cli to save the map, as well as a button that stops the localization and removes the previously added displays, as well as kills the cartographer node.

The approach I end up using should be applicable to any launch file that adds new displays to RViz since I don't yet know what localization algorithm or future use this plugin and robot may have.

If anyone has some insight on how I might be able to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate your help.